# changing the contents of a text file

Tags: awk

I have a text file with the following contents.

```
sadhana         88/17  =   5.2
alex           189/41  =   4.6
dominic         33/10  =   3.3
 ..
 ..
 ..
```

I would like to change the contents of the above file like this.

```
sadhana   88   17   5.2
alex     189   41   4.6
dominic  33    10   3.3
 ..
 ..
 ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you use sed? -

```
sed 's#/# #' | sed 's/=/ /'
```

or

```
sed -e 's#/# #' -e 's/=/ /'
```

Comment: There's a more concise way to do it with sed (`sed 's#[/=]# #g'`), but that is the job `tr` was invented to do anyway. See @BMW's solution.

Answer (score 4):

tr can do the job easily

```
tr "/=" " " < file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`

```
awk -v OFS="\t" -F"[ /=]*" '{$1=$1}1' file
sadhana 88      17      5.2
alex    189     41      4.6
dominic 33      10      3.3
```

Comment: You could just use `awk -F"[ /=]*" '{$1=$1}1' OFS="\t" file` so you don't have to explicitly list every field number. FWIW I'd never put a variable assignment where the file names go (`awk 'script' OFS='\t' file`) unless I had to change a variable value between files. I'd always use (`awk -v OFS='\t' 'script' file`) so all variables are consistently available in the BEGIN section and IMHO it's clearer and more natural when reading a script left-to-right to see the initial variable settings before the start of the script rather than after it.